# I have a linux command that I need to work on Windows (i.e. Powershell)

Tags: bash, powershell, docker, docker-compose

I have inherited a linux command that deploys a docker stack. I need the equivalent Windows version of it. I can't seem to figure it out, as I'm new to docker.

```
docker stack deploy -c <(docker-compose config) --with-registry-auth $(basename $PWD)
```

What's the equivalent Windows (Powershell) command for the above? The part I can't figure out is the "<(docker-compose config)" part.

Answer (score 0):

If you have windows 10, you can actually install the flavor of linux from Microsoft Store.
You use this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) as reference.